# Is there a term describing a fish's mouth action as it breathes?

Tags: synonyms

I would wager there must be a term of art describing what a fish does as it breathes, normally, underwater. Any thoughts?

Comment: This isn't  a duplicate, because in this Q the fish is breathing normally underwater, and in the suggested duplicate, the fish is stranded on land.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on Biology; http://biology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

According to various source, Aquatic Respiration appears to be the definition for the act of acquiring oxygen for a fish although "aquatic" would be redundant in context of the OP.

Literarily, inspire could be used, if only by its secondary definition.

Comment: I think these are words to describe the breathing of fishes. I think OP is asking about the slow, partial opening and closing of the mouth as it breathes.

Comment: @Jim -- Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Both the following words suit perfectly to express the referred action of the fish when they

- gasp
- gulp

for breath or air.